# unix split FASTA using a loop, awk and split

Tags: unix, awk, split, fasta

I have a long list of data organised as below (INPUT).
I want to split the data up so that I get an output as below (desired OUTPUT).

The code below first identifies all the lines containing ">gi" and saves the linecount of those lines in an array called B.
Then, in a new file, it should replace those lines from array B with the shortened version of the text following the ">gi"

I figured the easiest way would be to split at "|", however this does not work (no separation happens with my code if i replace " " with "|")

My code is below and does split nicely after the " " if I replace the "|" by " " in the INPUT, however I get into trouble when I want to get the text between the [ ] brackets, which is NOT always there and not always only 2 words...:

```
B=$( grep -n ">gi" 1VAO_1DII_5fxe_all_hits_combined.txt | cut -d : -f 1)

 awk <1VAO_1DII_5fxe_all_hits_combined.txt >seqIDs_1VAO_1DII_5fxe_all_hits_combined.txt -v lines="$B" '
BEGIN {split(lines, a, " "); for (i in a) change[a[i]]=1}
NR in change {$0 = ">" $4}
1
'
```

let me know if more explanations are needed!

INPUT:

```
 >gi|9955361|pdb|1E0Y|A:1-560 Chain A, Structure Of The D170sT457E DOUBLE MUTANT OF VANILLYL- Alcohol Oxidase
 MSKTQEFRPLTLPPKLSLSDFNEFIQDIIRIVGSENVEVISSKDQIVDGSYMKPTHTHDPHHVMDQDYFLASAIVA

 >gi|557721169|dbj|GAD99964.1|:1-560 hypothetical protein NECHADRAFT_63237 [Byssochlamys spectabilis No. 5]
 MSETMEFRPMVLPPNLLLSEFNGFIRETIRLVGCENVEVISSKDQIHDGSYMDPRHTHDPHHIMEQDYFLASAIVAPRNV
```

desired OUTPUT:

```
 >1E0Y
 MSKTQEFRPLTLPPKLSLSDFNEFIQDIIRIVGSENVEVISSKDQIVDGSYMKPTHTHDPHHVMDQDYFLASAIVAPRNV

 >GAD99964.1 Byssochlamys spectabilis No. 5
 MSETMEFRPMVLPPNLLLSEFNGFIRETIRLVGCENVEVISSKDQIHDGSYMDPRHTHDPHHIMEQDYFLASAIVA
```

Comment: This is too complex for the non-obsessive reader to try and parse. Can't you make a 20 character 2 line set of input that would allow people to easily see the problem and help you solve?  Also I think showing input and then output makes for a more natural flow of problem solving. Good luck.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, edit has been made

Comment: [edit] your question again and use the `{}` button to format your input and output just like you did your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in one step with awk (gnu awk):

```
awk -F'|' '/^>gi/{a=1;match($NF,/\[([^]]*)]/, b);print ">"$4" "b[1];next}a{print}!$0{a=0}' input > output
```

In a more readable way:

```
/^>gi/ {  # when the line starts with ">gi"
    a=1;  # set flag "a" to 1
    # extract the eventual part between brackets in the last field
    match($NF,"\\[([^]]*)]", b);
    print ">"$4" "b[1]; # display the line
    next # jump to the next record
}

a { print } # when "a" (allowed block) display the line

!$0 { a=0 } # when the line is empty, set "a" to 0 to stop the display
```

Comment: this gives me only the > character followed by an empty line. I do need the line > 4th element between "|" and the bits between the [] brackets.I do not understand what happens in the match() line.

Comment: Ok. now it is clear what happens with match. can the print command be modified to not just print the 4th element of the line but actually the 4th element of the line using the "|"separator?

Comment: Never mind, ignore previous comment... I was confused by myself. It works fins. Thx

Comment: You should mention that's gawk-specific due to the 3rd arg for match(). Also, the 2nd arg for `match()` is a regexp not a string, so you should be using regexp delimiters `/.../`, not string delimiters, `"..."` as the latter causes awk to have to parse the enclosed text twice - once to convert from a string to a regexp and then again to use as a regexp. That's why you had to double the escapes `"\\[..."`, one for each pass of the interpeter. Use `/\[([^]]*)]/` instead.